# Node.js problems with PostgreSQL Database Insert operation

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, express

I'm trying to Make a registration form using postgresql, Nodejs and Express.I have only One problem for now, Inserting Data.

I want to insert the user data into a table called `users(id int, username text, password text)`.

I get no Errors. Database is hosted on Heroku. Result from inserting is: Nothing. No errors. No data inserted.

index.js MainJS

```
var pg = require('pg');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var cool = require('cool-ascii-faces');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


//BodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
app.locals.log = function(arg) {console.log("works");}
  response.render('pages/index');

});


app.get('/db', function(request, response){
    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
        client.query('SELECT * FROM test_table', function (err, result){
            done();
            if (err) {console.error(err); response.send("ERROR " + err);}
            else {response.render('pages/db', {results :result.rows}); }
        });
    });
});

app.get('/register', function(request, response){
    response.render('pages/register');

});

app.get('/cool', function(request, response){
    response.send(cool());
});


//maps controller 
var userController = require('./userController.js');

app.get('/users/register', userController.register);
app.post('/users/register', userController.register);

app.get('/users/login', userController.login);
app.post('/users/login', userController.login);

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

registration template ejs register.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <% include ../partials/header.ejs %>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Register</h1>
<% include ../partials/nav.ejs %>
<div class="container">
<h2>Register</h2>

<form method="POST" action="/users/register">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

userController.js

```
var pg = require('pg');

var registerUser = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, password) VALUES (1, 'Kris', 'blahbda');";


module.exports = {
  login: function (req, res) {
    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
        client.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (err, result){
            done();
            if (err) {console.error(err); res.send("ERROR " + err);}
            else {res.render('pages/db', {results :result.rows}); }
        });
    });
  },
  register: function (req, res) {
      var username = req.body.username;
      pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
          client.query(registerUser, function (err, result){
              done();
              if (err) {console.error(err); res.send("ERROR " + err);}
              else {res.render('pages/db', {results :result.rows}); }
          });
      });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't do node.js but my immediate thought is that there is an implicit transaction that is created but you don't commit or properly close the connection before moving on. This is common with python and perl.

Comment: Alright, i'll see what i can do... i started the project from heroku , pulled with git .. but anyways

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,
Chang the query insert inside userController.js

```
var registerUser = 'INSERT INTO users ("id", "username", "password") VALUES ($1,$2,$3);', ['1', 'Kris', 'blahbda'];
```